# What is a shared library, and how do you manually install a .dll for Python?

Tags: python, dll, shared-libraries, hid

I'm trying to control my Elgato Stream Deck via Python, and am trying to follow the steps here: https://python-elgato-streamdeck.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/backend_libusb_hidapi.html

There are further instructions here:
https://github.com/libusb/hidapi#build-instructions

Unfortunately I can't get anything to work, and I know I'm not setting things up properly because I'm not sure what to do with the downloaded .dll and .lib files. In Pycharm, I always get the error:

> ('Probe failed to find any functional HID backend.', {'libusb': TransportError("No suitable LibUSB HIDAPI library found on this system. Is the 'hidapi.dll' library installed?")})

The instructions I can find seem more advanced than what I know how to do.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Fedora? I have seen this error and the following should resolve the problem:

```
sudo dnf install hidapi
```